# Django MongoDB, create models based on other model

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I have one model Foo, it will have a field lets call it "parameters_names". I want to save this model then create a new model with those paramaters_names as fields of the new model.

so for example Foo:

> parameters: "Name, Surname, ID_number"

```
NEW MODEL: 
name = CharField()
surname = CharField()
id_number = CharField()
```

So the new models might always be different.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
model FooParams:
    foo = ForeignKey(Foo)
    param = CharField()
    value = CharField()
```

Comment: HOw would I create those, it has to happen in the app it self.

Comment: When saving model Foo, add the params to FooParams.